# Android Studio: Facebook image won't load

Tags: android, facebook, firebase

I might me doing something wrong. I managed to get the facebook image with user.getPhotoUrl but it only shows a low res picture.

So I tried using this code.

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    if (user != null) {
        String name = user.getDisplayName();
        nameView.setText(user.getDisplayName());
        Picasso.with(this).load("https://graph.facebook.com/"+user.getUid()+"/picture?type=large").into(profileImage);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it!

```
 for(UserInfo profile : user.getProviderData()) {
            if(profile.getProviderId().equals(getString("facebook.com"))) {
                facebookUserId = profile.getUid();
            }
        }

String photoUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + facebookUserId + "/picture?height=500";
Picasso.with(this).load(photoUrl).into(profileImage);
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to get a picture of a quality that you want. Just replace `width=200` with the width you want and `height=200` with the height you want.

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/"+user.getUid()+"/picture?type=large&width=200&height=200"
```

Comment: I guess your link is correct. Only problem is that it won't show an image in my application.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Picasso, but are you sure you're passing the right `context` and/or `profileImage`?

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, I think the String from user.getUid is the firebase/facebook id and not the facebook id. I guess there is a difference but I'm not sure where to get the facebook id from.